# Bonecp creates more bonecp-pool-watch-thread and bonecp-keep-alive-scheduler threads

Tags: connection-pooling, bonecp

We are creating DB connection using `JNDI` with `BoneCP` connection pooling . After some time bonecp creates more `com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer` , `bonecp-pool-watch-thread`  and `bonecp-keep-alive-scheduler` active threads. So it takes more memory . It leads to JVM crash.

How to fix this issue ? Any configuration to control the number of threads.

**Name: BoneCP-pool-watch-thread**

```
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@42256c51 
Total blocked: 0 Total waited: 1 

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186) 
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043) 
java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:374) 
com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.run(PoolWatchThread.java:64) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**Name: com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer**

```
State: WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@7035679c 
Total blocked: 0 Total waited: 1 

Stack trace: 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135) 
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151) 
com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer.run(Finalizer.java:131) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**Name: BoneCP-keep-alive-scheduler**

```
State: TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@327a219f 
Total blocked: 0 Total waited: 5 

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226) 
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082) 
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090) 
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Guava library bug. However pls note that you should consider BoneCP deprecated in favour of HikariCP.